# jQuery tooltip not horizontally aligned?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

I have created a simple jQuery & CSS based tooltip which is not aligned horizontally even though i made positioning relative for the parent anchor link element.

If i set the width of the tooltip to 100px or something else it works but the content may extend so I want to avoid defining the width.

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="single-session-speakers">

<div class="single_session_speaker_thumb iva_tip">
<a href="#"><img alt="Anne-Marie" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
<span class="ttip">Anne-Marie</span></a>
</div>

<div class="single_session_speaker_thumb iva_tip">
<a href="#"><img alt="Kristin Ellison" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
<span class="ttip">Kristin</span></a>
</div>

<div class="single_session_speaker_thumb iva_tip">
<a href="#"><img alt="John McWade" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
<span class="ttip">John McWade</span></a>
</div>

<div class="single_session_speaker_thumb iva_tip">
<a href="#"><img alt="Chris Converse" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
<span class="ttip">Chris Converse Mark</span></a>
</div>

</div>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$('.iva_tip').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('span.ttip').fadeIn();
}, function () {
    $(this).find('span.ttip').fadeOut();
});
```

**CSS Code**

```
.single_session_speaker_thumb {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 4% 4% 0;
}

.single_session_speaker_thumb a { display: block;}

.ttip {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 115%;
    left: -50%;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 15px;
    margin-left: 6px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #22222b;
    color: #d1d1de;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
 }

.ttip::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -6px;
    border-top-color: inherit;
    border-top: 6px solid #333333;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? Please let me know. Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/femiva/bw6hbrq9/2/)

Comment: Did you mean "vertical aligned"?

Comment: In Question title i asked about horizontally not vertical. I have the vertical position to top currently.

Comment: You mean align the tooltip in reference to the gray box as follows? https://jsfiddle.net/bw6hbrq9/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, tooltip's width depends on content. Then you will need to align it using `JS` code instead of `CSS` as follows:

```
// Getting position based on width of gray-box and tooltip
var left = (grayBoxWidth - tooltipWidth) / 2; 
// Setting calculated left-position to tooltip element
$(this).find('span.ttip').css('left', left).fadeIn();
```

See this **[working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bw6hbrq9/4/)**

Comment: Didn't realised about that the tooltip width is depending on the content. Thanks for the output @leo.fccx, appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of issues is allways dificult to handle . What i could do to help is recomend this awasome plugin [Qtip2](http://qtip2.com/). This have a lot of features and you dont need to worry about with things like your problem now. Have a look in to the demos [here](http://qtip2.com/demos)

Comment: I have not asked which plugin to use or recommend. BTW the plugin you recommended is of size 45KB.